# System.ArgumentException occurred

Tags: c#, pocketpc

I'm getting a strange behavior. This is the code:

```
...
private Object lockobj = new Object();
private Dictionary<String, BasicTagBean> toVerifyTags = null;

public void verifyTags(List<BasicTagBean> tags)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    lock (lockobj)
    {
        foreach (BasicTagBean tag in tags)
        {
            if (!alreadyVerified.ContainsKey(tag.EPC))
            {
                toVerifyTags.Add(tag.EPC, tag);
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Sometimes I got this exception

```
'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

at this line of code:

```
toVerifyTags.Add(tag.EPC, tag);
```

the exception refer to wrong add of an already existing element into collection, but I check this. Maybe a thread problem but application output shows always the same thread id. I'm using c# pocketpc version 3.5.

Comment: What is `toVerifyTags` and where is it created?  Where is `alreadyVerified` created?

Comment: Could you add the declaration of `toVerifyTags` in your code sample ? Also, the exception seems pretty accurate, you already have that key in your dictionary.

Comment: You aren't checking to see if the key already exists in `toVerifyTags`...

Comment: You seem to have two different dictionaries: alreadyVerified and toVerifyTags. Just because alreadyVerfied does not contain a certain key, it doesn't mean toVerfyTags does not contain it either.

Comment: Trivial mistake, sorry. I update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception seems to tell you that the key you are trying to add in `toVerifyTags` already exists. You weren't checking if the key already existed in the right dictionary.

```
public void verifyTags(List<BasicTagBean> tags)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    lock (lockobj)
    {
        foreach (BasicTagBean tag in tags)
        {
            if (!toVerifyTags.ContainsKey(tag.EPC))
            {
                toVerifyTags.Add(tag.EPC, tag);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My fault. There is only a dictionary, sorry. I update the question.